# how to handle different rank authorization in a REST api

Tags: node.js, api, rest, go

I am designing a REST API in which there are several user types:

- disabled user
- standard user
- support user
- admin
- root

for each user, there are certain properties assigned to them in a relational database.
For example files, messages, payments, ...

Let's say I want users with higher ranks to be able to handle data related to lower ranks (e.g. an admin can modify a standard user's properties)
How can I implement it in a way that I make sure the authorization functionality is separated from the process (CRUD process).

I want something like this:

```
api.Get("/users/:id", authorization, processHandler)
```

I am using the echo framework and Golang, but I don't think that really matters. I am looking for a general solution independent of language.

Comment: Use a middleware http handler to wrap requests & inspect for auth headers. The auth handler can then set a request context value with a users "role". Downstream handlers can inspect the request context value & decide what runtime behavior to enforce.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have Roles and Permissions problems, that problem has a solution when you control the access level by JWT token (for example).

You have a table with enabled system permissions and your users have associated or assigned permissions, this "association" can be managed through the Roles and Permissions manager (CRUD). So when you need to associate permissions to a user, you have to create a relationship between the permissions and the user. Then, send the new "state" in the token (JWT).

So finally you have a "middleware" on your routes like this

```golang
api.Get ("/ users /: id", authorization, processHandler)
```

And your `authorization` role has the responsibility to check if your user has the permissions to use the endpoint.

Comment: The problem is that this way I need to create a separate middleware for each route. Because every route has a different task and manages a different property. Then I need to check if the property that the user wants to manage is not relevant to a user with a higher rank.